# Applescript to play multiple iphoto slideshows

Tags: script, iphoto, slideshow

I would like to present an iphoto slideshow that repeats/loops until I decide to advance it to the next slideshow that then repeats until I then advance it to the next group of slides and so on. Without having to return to the iphoto screen/desktop and interrferring the flo of the presentation. Can anyone write me a bit of script for this?

Comment: or should I just use IDVD to run my slideshows from?